# ClassNotFoundException using Spring Boot and Spring Cloud

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I am trying to use feature from *Spring Cloud* (ex: Feign or Zipkin Client) in a *Spring Boot* micro-service. Whenever I introduce the Spring Cloud dependencies into the pom.xml I get the following error at startup:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.Versioned
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
```

Below is a sample pom.xml causing this. I am currently on *Spring Boot 2.0.0.RELEASE* and *Spring Cloud Finchley.M8*.

**What am I doing wrong? Should I switch to another version of Spring Cloud?**

**UPDATE**: It's not me who's doing it wrong, even [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) projects demonstrate this issue. To repro:

1. Go to https://start.spring.io/.
2. Enter Web, JPA and Feign as dependencies
3. Download the project.
4. Launch in IDE (in my case Spring Tool Suite) and the exception will be thrown at startup.

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>io.urig</groupId>
    <artifactId>inventory</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>inventory</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.M8</spring-cloud.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: They are built to work together. I just created a project with your same dependencies and I don't get that exception. Probably a corrupt jar in local maven repo. Try `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository`

Comment: Thanks @spencergibb. I did that but still getting the error :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was a corrupt Maven package. Deleting my `.m2\repository` folder and running `mvn spring-boot:run` to downloaded dependencies and run my app resolved the issue.

Comment: Please accept your own answer and close this question.